# Error when using R betadisper function

Tags: r, vegan

The 'betadisper' funtion in vegan [R] calculates the multivariate dispersion of a group of sites based on their distances

I have a distance matrix with multiple groups of sites:

```
dis <- vegdist(correct_tree_data)
```

I created my 'groups' using the 'factor' function (23 levels for 23 groups of sites), and each group has a different no. of sites

```
groups <- factor(c(rep(1,144), rep(2,49), rep(3,121), rep(4,81), rep(5,81), rep(6,81), rep(7,36), rep(8,289), rep(9,324), rep(10,225), rep(11,256), rep(12,225), rep(13,289), rep(14,289), rep(15,144), rep(16,225), rep(17,225), rep(18,225), rep(19,225), rep(20,225), rep(21,225), rep(22,225), rep(23,225)), labels = c("s1_05","s2_05","s3_05","s4_05","s5_05","s6_05","s7_05","s1_10","s2_10","s3_10","s4_10","s5_10","s6_10","s7_10","s8_10","s1_15","s2_15","s3_15","s4_15","s5_15","s6_15","s7_15","s8_15"))
```

When using the 'betadisper' function, however, I get the following error message:

> mod <- betadisper(dis, groups)
>
> Error in pts[groups == i, , drop = FALSE] :    (subscript) logical
>   subscript too long

The levels do match the amount of groups in the distance matrix as well as the no. of replicates in each group

What else may be contributing to this error?

Comment: Where does `correct_tree_data` come from? Can you please make this example fully reproducible? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Based on some experimenting I just did with these functions I'd say that the answer is that the `groups` factor length doesn't really match the `dis` object's dimensions, but it's impossible to really tell what's going on in your case without a reproducible example.

Comment: This would be simpler if you used just `rep(1:23, each = c(144, 49, 121, ...))`

Answer (score 0):

As long as the dimensions/lengths match this function should work fine:

```
require(vegan)
data(varespec)

dis   <- vegdist(varespec)
group <- factor(rep("grazed", NROW(varespec)))
mod   <- betadisper(dis, group)
mod
```

> Homogeneity of multivariate dispersions
>
> Call: betadisper(d = dis, group = group)
>
> No. of Positive Eigenvalues: 15 No. of Negative Eigenvalues: 8
>
> Average distance to median: grazed 
>   0.4255
>
> Eigenvalues for PCoA axes:  PCoA1  PCoA2  PCoA3  PCoA4  PCoA5  PCoA6 
>   PCoA7  PCoA8 
>   1.7552 1.1334 0.4429 0.3698 0.2454 0.1961 0.1751 0.1284

However if your factor length is longer than it should be you'll get that error:

```
group <- c(group, "extra data")
betadisper(dis, group)
```

> Error in pts[groups == i, , drop = FALSE] :    (subscript) logical
>   subscript too long

I know that you don't think this is the problem you're having, so if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can investigate your specific case further.

Comment: Hi @Hack, thank you for your input. I though that rep meant the number of cells or replicates within a site. After correcting for the number of sites within a group it worked. Thanks again!